# Replace vintage speaker connection by modern one

Tags: audio, cables, speakers, banana-jack

So, I have a vintage Pioneer hi-fi installation and I want to use it in a recording studio. It features two passive speakers and one amplifier. My problem is that the speakers need to be connected to the amp by tightening speaker wire to them using screws - and I want to be able to easily attach and detach them.

The amp has speaker plugs (similar to the modern binding posts) which look like
[this http://www.ultraelectronicactive.com/Media/Equip/Connectors+Cables/Pioneer-Speaker-Plugs.jpg](http://www.ultraelectronicactive.com/Media/Equip/Connectors+Cables/Pioneer-Speaker-Plugs.jpg)
and the connection on the speaker side is kind of like a binding post, like
[image: this]
<sub>(source: [stereobarn.com](http://stereobarn.com/wp-content/uploads/speaker-terminal-caps-256x256.jpg))</sub>

but it's just simple screws holding the wire.

Now, my questions is: does anyone know if there already exists some cable connector which fits these connections? Or does anyone have a suggestion on how to make one myself? I have a basic knowledge of soldering. I would love to just have a 1/4" or banana plug speaker cable which I could easily plug in or remove when I want to. I am aware of the possibility to plug in banana jacks into binding posts, but they would in no way fit mine.

Edit: I also can't seem to open my passive speakers to change out the connections.

Comment: Why not use standard spring speaker connectors?

Comment: I dislike having to put the ends of speaker wire in a connector. I prefer have a proper jack which you can plug in (I also play guitar and bass etc, so that's why). Oh and I also can't seem to open the passive speaker to change out the connections :/

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking now. Just use spade lugs.

Comment: If you can't open the speakers can you remove the driver from the front to gain access to the rear?

Comment: @transistor; nope already tried that .. :/ I was thinking of some way to connect something to the vintage connectors, like [this](http://www.americanmusical.com/ItemImages/Large/79993.jpg) instead of opening up and replacing :)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams; that would be the final solution yes, but again: I **really** prefer a jack or plug type of situation :)

Comment: If you're happy with that then purchase inline jack sockets and fork crimp terminals and make up adaptors similar the image you linked to. One for each speaker and two for the amp. Do a neat job and they will look fine - if anyone ever sees them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make your own adapter. Purchase the correct types of connectors, a suitable piece of wire, and crimp/solder them on. Easier than sourcing a random non-standard adapter.

Or use a spade to banana plug adaptor.

[image]

Comment: Well, that's what I'm looking for. But what is the correct type of connector for a screw hole? Because that's what the speaker has as a connection :p transistor suggested to use fork crimp terminals as connectors and then connect them with jacks - which is kind of an alternative to what you're saying. I think I might go with either of your suggestions, thanks!

Comment: @mbauwens "fork crimp terminals" those are called spade connectors, not fork. See update.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with my vintage Sansui receiver. The speaker terminals are the screw type which only accept up to 11 awg thick straight cable. I got high quality cable and created a "bridge where I have a 5-way post on a board for L/R speakers (either you can do biwire at this point or at the speaker termination end) and connect a stripped 11 awg wire connected from the amplifier to the 5-way and then a banana plug or spade from the 5-way to the speaker If you use excellent quality cable, there will be no sonic degradation by bridging the old terminal to a 5-way.

The other option is to find a shop that does amplifier repairs and ask if they can swap out the original binding posts with 5-ways. That is my plan if I ever have to have it repaired for other reasons.